# Comparing lists in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to compare two lists and I'm using the decorator `@pytest.mark.parametrize`.

So, my code is:

```py
import pytest

List1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
List2 = ['a', 'c', 'd']


@pytest.mark.parametrize('expected',List1)
@pytest.mark.parametrize('actual',List2)
def test_compare(expected,actual):
    assert expected == actual
```

In this case I want to have 3 tests:

- `List1[0] == List2[0]`
- `List[1] == List[1]`
- `List[2] == List[2]`

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: This code does 9 tests . I need only 3. I need compare List1[0] with List2[0], List1[1] with List2[1] etc. However I don't want compare List1[0] with List2[1] for example. How can I do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can `zip` the lists in `parametrize`

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['a', 'c', 'd']


@pytest.mark.parametrize('lists', zip(list1, list2))
def test_compare(lists):
    assert lists[0] == lists[1]
```

or

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('expected, actual', zip(list1, list2))
def test_compare(expected, actual):
    assert actual == expected
```

Output

```
PASSED                                [ 33%]
FAILED                                [ 66%]

example_test.py:24 (test_compare[b-c])
b != c

Expected :b
Actual   :c

example_test.py:28: AssertionError
FAILED                                [100%]

example_test.py:24 (test_compare[c-d])
c != d

Expected :c
Actual   :d

example_test.py:28: AssertionError
```

Answer (score 0):

To change multiple arguments simultaneously, parameterize them at the same time:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('expected, actual',
[("a", "a"),
 ("b", "c"),
 ("c", "d"),
])
def test_compare(expected, actual):
    assert expected == actual
```